# Ubuntu GFX stops software from using hardware acceleration

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

I have a real big problem, unless the software I'm trying to use is native to Ubuntu 20.04 it will not work unless the software has the ability to disable hardware acceleration.

EG
Google-chrome will ONLY work if hardware acceleration is disabled, otherwise I have to run it inside a terminal, the same goes for Discord, gedit and other native Ubuntu apps work fine, even Firefox has to be run inside a terminal, PuTTY too.

Just in case someone says to update the GFX drivers, there IS NO updated drivers either from conical, or the manufacturers.  Ubuntu sees the GFX chip as a Radeon Sumo (6530D), and the only Linux version that Radeon has on the drivers page is for Ubuntu 14.04, nothing for Ubuntu 20.04, I did try the 14.04 version, but it wouldn't install because of the libqtcore4 dependency is missing but when I try to install the libqtcore4 libraries, it says that the libraries depend on fglrx core which is not being installed, so that won't work either.

So, I'm assuming that the default drivers are useless and I may have to revert back to Ubuntu 14.04, so that I can use the manufacturers drivers.

Comment: Whether you launch an application from a terminal or from a `.desktop` shortcut should not make any difference.  Also, all of these applications have native debian based Linux clients. Firefox is even in official Ubuntu repositories. There are no new downloadable drivers for new versions of Ubuntu for these cards because support is integrated into the Linux kernel.  For these reasons, your question is not really answerable because it is predicated on conclusions that you made that are not quite right.

Comment: It would be better if you describe the problem exactly as it manifests. Telling us that something "doesn't work" does not really describe the problem in a way that we might understand what's going on. It's fine to guess at possible causes, but take caution not to make assumptions.  If you will edit your question and include more details, we might be able to understand the problem better. As a diagnostic step, you might want to try to run Ubuntu in a live session to see if the problem persists (Try Ubuntu from bootable installation media)